# Alternative Access Mapping

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, 2016, alternate-access-mapping

We have 2-WFE, 2-Application with Search and 1-OWA servers, we have a Web Application created and mapped to WFE-1 server like http://wfe1, we need to add one more Public URL to this application, but already wfe1 default 80 port is using some other application

My question is, shall I point Public URL to WFE2 server?

Comment: Another public url for same web application or you want create another web application? Are u not using load balancer in front of wfe as u have 2?

Comment: Another public url for same web application, we are not using load balencer

Answer (score 0):

You can define Host Name in IIS Bindings so that several web applications run on port 80. Make one e.g., http://myapp1 and second one e.g., http://myapp2, and ensure SharePoint AAM includes both.

Idea is usually to run all SP web apps on all WFEs, so pointing address to specific one WFE may not be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You cannont point two different URL for same web application in default zone. But you can do the following.

1. Recommended way is

   - Extended the Web Application into different zone ( intranet, internet, custom,extranet).
   - this will create another IIS site but pointing to same content as you default zone.
   - Now you update the IIS bindings with new URL & SSL (if required).
   - Test the url

     2. 2nd method, just simply edit the Public URL from the Central Admin > AAM, and put that URL in any zone other than Default.

[read this about AAM](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepoint_strategery/2013/05/27/alternate-access-mappings-aams-explained/)